# Как с помощью функции сравнить два словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
documents = [
    {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
    {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
    {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
  ]
directories = {
    '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2', '5455 028765'],
    '2': ['10006'],
    '3': []
  }
```

Есть два словаря, По заданию над написать функцию которая будет сравнивать значение и если значение из первого словаря совпадает с тем что во втором слваре, надо вывести ключ из второго словаря.
То есть 'number' : '10006' - из первого словаря
И во втором словаре есть это значение, в ключе '2', значит и выводим 2

Хоть убейте даже начать писать функцию не могу(мыслей даже нет), если не кодом, то хотя бы натолкните на мысль

Answer (score 2):

Держите логику "в лоб". Функцию опишите уже сами, основывясь или переработав мою логику.

Первое, словарь `documents` нам не нужен как словарь, а только данные, которые находятся под ключами. Поэтому сдеалем список, который содержит данные значения и сохраним в переменную `result`

```py
>>> documents = [
...     {"type": "passport", "number": "2207 876234", "name": "Василий Гупкин"},
...     {"type": "invoice", "number": "11-2", "name": "Геннадий Покемонов"},
...     {"type": "insurance", "number": "10006", "name": "Аристарх Павлов"}
...   ]
>>> directories = {
...     '1': ['2207 876234', '11-2', '5455 028765'],
...     '2': ['10006'],
...     '3': []
...   }
>>> result = []
>>> for i in documents:
...   for key, value in i.items():
...     result.append(value)
... 
>>> result
['passport', '2207 876234', 'Василий Гупкин', 'invoice', '11-2', 'Геннадий Покемонов', 'insurance', '10006', 'Аристарх Павлов']
```

С этой переменной и будем сравнивать.

Теперь пробежимся по второму словарю, будем брать каждое значение, которое находится в списке под каждым ключом и спрашивать: "Есть ли такое значение в переменной `result`".

```
>>> for key, value in directories.items():
...   for _ in value:
...     if _ in result:
...       print(key)
... 
1
1
2
```

На выходе у нас ключи, которые содержат совпадения.

Comment: В том то и дело, я знаю как это расписать без функции, а вот с функцией